# React router v4.2.2: using a string instead of function inside component prop of Route results in error

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am using react-router v4.2.2 and am trying to use a function to spit out a list of routes with a component property value of "project.title", taken from a reducer I am using. However, when I write:

```
return <Route key={i} exact path={`/${project.title}`} exact component={project.title}/>
```

using the project.title part results in this error:

> Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` of type `string` supplied
>   to `Route`, expected `function`.

but when I replace project.title with an actual component like Project1:

```
return <Route key={i} exact path={`/${project.title}`} exact component={Project1}/>
```

then it's fine.

Is there a way I can use the titles of each project, from my reducer, in this function, without this error popping up?

here is the whole container code, in case it's helpful:

```
import React from 'react';
import Project1 from '../components/project1.js';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import ProjectCards from '../containers/project_cards.js';

class App extends React.Component{
    render() {
        var createRoutes = this.props.projects.map((project, i) => {
            return <Route key={i} exact path={`/${project.title}`} exact component={project.title}/>
        });
        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={ProjectCards}/>
                {createRoutes}
            </Switch>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        projects: state.projects
    };
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(App));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just pass a string as the component if a route -- it expects an actual component. What I would recommend is saving all your components in some kind object which then you can access:

```
const projects = {
  Project1,
  …
};
…
<Route key={i} exact path={`/${project.title}`} exact component={projects[project.title]}/>
```

Comment: I placed an object in the render function, and am trying to get all the links to direct to the first project (component={projects[1]}) just to test that this works, but now no component is being rendered when the project rerenders after a card has been clicked :/

Comment: oh! I just replaced that code with the exact code you suggested: projects[project.title] and this worked! I'm sorry, I don't know why I didn't do that to start off with- the logic was unfamiliar to me and I think I got confused and tried to get to the first project in the object, as though the object was placed in an array of objects. Sorry about that, and thank you so much for your help!